# What is the basic physics of current-electricity?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors

Why current decreases when length of resistor increases and How the speed of electricity is almost $c$ (speed of light)?

Comment: this link, and the site in general http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Answer (score 1):

Answer for question 2:
The speed of electricity is in fact the speed of electromagnetic wave propagation or the spread of electromagnetic field inside the conductor. That is not the speed of the electrons, no object having mass can reach the speed of light.
But why the speed of light? It's because the light is an electromagnetic wave.
The speed of the electromagnetic wave is c=299792458 m/s only when the medium is the vacuum. In another medium, it is slower by a constant.

Comment: the speed of electricity actually means the speed of signal so if a charge is very long distance in wire(from the terminal) the signal will reach there or electrons will  start motion after the signal reaches there.  I know that electrons have very low velocity and I am not talking about that.

Comment: @PredakingAskboss I've answered you why the speed of electricity is the speed of light, it's because they are the same thing: electromagnetic wave propagation.

Comment: The electric fields move from terminal throughout the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The field due to the battery sets up a surface charge in the wire.  The surface charge is negative near the negative pole of the battery, and positive near the positive terminal, and varies more or less linearly along the wire.  The surface charge in turn sets up inside the wire an electric field which is constant across the diameter of the wire, and along the length.  This field accelerates electrons.

Comment: "charges sets up electric field which is constant across the diameter" It has a very big issue with it. Which is, E = V/d . Which means on increasing the lentgh of resistor E will decrease. Can you explain why the electric field remains same in cross-section? Hiw field number gets increased with increased diameter?

Comment: @PredakingAskboss Indeed, the field is weaker in longer wires.  Hence the current is lower.